# Swift IOS, How to capitalize letters of a sentance inputed by app user, example ; 4th letter and 6th letter?

Tags: ios, swift

The user inputs a sentence in text-field , 
and than enters the number 4 in a text-field and 6 in another text-field. It Capitalize the sentence at where the 4th letter is and the 6th letter is.

For Example user enters:  "there are 12 months in a year"

The output will be:  "theRe Are 12 months a year".

How to capitalize the 4th a 6th letters in a sentence?:

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It could be any two numbers the user enters, it dose not have to be 4th and 6th.It could be 1st and 2nd

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
func capitalize(string: String, positions: IndexSet) -> String {
    let range = (0..<string.count)
    guard string.count > 0,
        positions.allSatisfy({ range ~= $0 }) else {
        fatalError("Couldn't capitalize")
    }

    return String(string.enumerated().map{ (index, char) in
        return positions.contains(index) ? String(char).capitalized.first! : char
    })
}

var str = "there are 12 months in a year"
capitalize(string: str, positions: [3, 6])  //"theRe Are 12 months in a year"
```

---

If you'd like to only count letters, and to have the counting start by 1:

```
func capitalize(string: String, positions: IndexSet) -> String {

    guard string.count > 0 else {
        fatalError("There is nothing to capitalize")
    }

    let zeroBasedPositions = positions.map {$0 - 1}

    guard zeroBasedPositions.allSatisfy({ $0 >= 0 }) else {
        fatalError("The positions should be one-based")
    }

    let letterIndexes = string
        .enumerated()
        .filter { (index, char) in
            CharacterSet(charactersIn: String(char))
                .isSubset(of: CharacterSet.letters)
        }.map { $0.0 }

    guard let positionsMax = zeroBasedPositions.max(),
        positionsMax <= letterIndexes.count
        else {
            fatalError("There are only \(letterIndexes.count) letters")
    }

    let lettersToCapitalizeIndexes = zeroBasedPositions.map { letterIndexes[$0] }

    return String(string.enumerated().map{ (index, char) in
        if lettersToCapitalizeIndexes.contains(index) {
            return String(char).capitalized.first!
        } else {
            return char
        }
    })
}

var str = "there are 12 months in a year"
capitalize(string: str, positions: [4, 6])  //"theRe Are 12 months in a year"
```

Comment: I believe he doesn't count the spaces, from his example.

Comment: Thanks, so instead of using the positions [4,6] directly I just use the user inputs in the text-fields

Comment: @bob You choose the positions you want to capitalize by passing an array literal of integers in the `capitalize` function

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I've added that option

Comment: I had some trouble running the code, as I got errors

Comment: @bob Use this code in a playground. If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for more information

Comment: I used the code in a playground but it gives errors

Comment: @bob Did you `import Foundation`